# My custom post type redirect to edit.php after publish and update post in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I have created new custom post type - deals in wordpress and it is redirect to edit.php(posts listing) after the publish new deal post. so I want to redirect it to deals list page (http://mydemo.com/demo/edit.php?post_type=deals) so please help me.

I tried this code but it redirect all posts type to specified page.

```
add_filter( 'redirect_post_location', 'wpse_124132_redirect_post_location' );
/**
 * Redirect to the edit.php on post save or publish.
 */


function wpse_124132_redirect_post_location( $location ) {

    if ( isset( $_POST['save'] ) || isset( $_POST['publish'] ) )
        return admin_url( "edit.php?post_type=deals" );

    return $location;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use [get_post_type()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type) function.

Change your code to

```
function wpse_124132_redirect_post_location( $location ) {

    if ( 'deals' == get_post_type() ) {

    /* Custom code for 'deals' post type. */

        if ( isset( $_POST['save'] ) || isset( $_POST['publish'] ) )
            return admin_url( "edit.php?post_type=deals" );

    } 
    return $location;
}
```

**EDIT** : Since you are using `get_post_type()` outside of *The Loop* you'll need to pass the ID of the post,

`get_post_type($_POST['id'])`

Comment: It works like a charm. Thanks. I find it very strange that WP redirects other non-admin users to edit.php when they don't have permission to native posts. I also don't understand why WP does'nt step up permissions, it blows my mind that users are required to have 'edit_posts' to do anything in the admin backend.