# WordPress redirect to previous "All Posts" list after Save post or Publish

Tags: php, wordpress

I have many posts in my `post` custom post type and the "All Posts" is paged. When I click "Edit" link and want to edit some post, I want to auto redirect to real previous page I was.

For example I'm in the link `https://example.com/wp-admin/edit.php?paged=18` and enter into edit one post. I want to redirect to mentioned link (page 18) after publish or edited post.

I tried a code but seems doesn't work at all and it won't redirect after publishing post or edit.

```
function wp_redirect_post_location( $location ) {
  $prevurl = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    if ( 'post' == get_post_type() ) {

        if ( isset( $_POST['save'] ) || isset( $_POST['publish'] ) )
            return $prevurl;

    } 
    return $location;
} 

add_filter( 'redirect_post_location', 'wp_redirect_post_location' );
```

And also tried this but didn't worked:

```
add_action( 'wp_after_insert_post', 'redirect_after_save_post'); 

function get_redirect_url(){
  $prevurl = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    if (isset($_GET['post_type'])){
        $page = $_GET['post_type'];
        return $prevurl;
    }
}

function redirect_after_save_post($post_id){
    wp_redirect(get_redirect_url());
    exit;
}
```

The second code redirect to `https://example.com/wp-admin/post.php` after publishing post, while I want to redirect to `https://example.com/wp-admin/edit.php?paged=18` (Where I entered to post's edit). Or if I'm in `https://example.com/wp-admin/edit.php?paged=15` and edit one post from there, after publishing that post, redirect back to `https://example.com/wp-admin/edit.php?paged=15`

Is there any solution or any other code to do this what I want? Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23821977/my-custom-post-type-redirect-to-edit-php-after-publish-and-update-post-in-wordpr

Comment: Check the above link

Comment: @wisdom-ighofose That code redirect to one static URL. I just edited my question. look at the end of my question. I want it to redirect back to last page I was

Comment: You should pass in the page ID

Comment: @wisdom-ighofose Can you add your reply with what you are saying? Currently wordpress can't save previous page id in session as I tried.